# Deploying bitbucket artifact to downloads

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have tried uploading test coverage results from pipeline to downloads.
I have the results as an artifact folder (dir/**).
I have followed this guide:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publish-and-link-your-build-artifacts-872137736.html

so my bitbucket-pipelines.yml code is:

```
pipelines:

default:
  - step:
      name: unit tests cover report
      image: aztec2docker/polymer-testing-docker
      artifacts:
        - unit-test-cover-report**
      script:
        - npm i
        - npm run test-cover
  - step:
      name: upload
      script:
        - curl -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"unit-test-cover-report"
```

It works for single files but not for a folder.
So my question is:
How do I upload a full artifact folder to bitbucket downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of way to do upload multiple files.

**Option 1**: create a `zip` or `tar.gz` archive from your folder and upload this archive to the downloads. There is a Bitbucket Pipe you can use to upload the file: [bitbucket-upload-file](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file/src/master/)

```
- step:
    name: upload
    script:
      - zip report.zip unit-test-cover-report-folder
      - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.1.2
          variables:
            BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
            BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
            FILENAME: 'report.zip'
```

**Option 2**: you can upload multiple files in a single API call,as mentioned in the [Bitbucket API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads):

```
- curl -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"file-1" --form files=@"file-2"
```

Comment: This worked for me but I also installed the zip command like following: - apt-get update && apt-get install --yes zip. Without this I got zip command not found.